# Sqlite query with random values, why do I get always the same results?

Tags: sqlite

Here is my code,
I try to perform random queries on my Sqlit databse.

I end up always with the same values !!

Please can somebody show me direction?

Thans!

```
    int i2=gerRank(livello);
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(i2);
    Toast.makeText(this,Integer.toString(i1),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Cursor parolaCursor = db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT _id, english, korean, difficulty FROM ordinato WHERE difficulty < "
                    + Integer.toString(i1)+ " ORDER BY _id", null);

    parolaCursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: Not knowing ANYTHING about the content of your DB its hard to say, but if there are no values for difficulty >= 0, that would do it.  Its even harder still when it isn't clear what language you are using.

Comment: did you verify, that you indeed get random values? I dunno what language you use around that query but dont you normally have to tell the rng what the limit for its values is? just curious, is the i1 actually different everytime?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste yes, 'i1' it is different every time

Comment: @Scott Hunter there are values for difficulty >=0

Comment: can you provide some data? what values are there for difficulty? what happens if you run this against your database directly with different values comparing to difficulty, do you get different results then? or is it the same? if so your problem may be situated within your data and not so much in your code.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste the fun is that I get a new random every time, the cursor is different because it has different length, but always same result on top ...

Comment: no i mean if you can pass your query directly to the database (maybe with a command line tool or sth idk about sqlite...) and insert that value that you get from your rng "by hand" like

SELECT _id, english, korean, difficulty FROM ordinato WHERE difficulty < 1 ORDER BY _id

and try different values like 2,3,4...100,1000...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Solved the issue, please see the new code:

```
int i2=gerRank(livello);
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(i2);
    Cursor parolaCursor = db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT _id, english, korean, difficulty FROM ordinato WHERE difficulty < "
                    + Integer.toString(i1)+ " ORDER BY difficulty DESC", null);
    parolaCursor.moveToFirst();
```

The trick is ORDER BY difficulty DESC